# How to split a table into two tables and linking records with crosslink ID's

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, split

I need some help with splitting an old customer database into customers and addresses

for example:

Lets call the old table `TB_old`
and the 2 new ones `new_customer` and `new_address`

**TB_old** have the following columns:

```
cust_id, firstname, lastname, address, city, postalcode, phone, email, password
```

**new_customers** got:

```
cust_id(new,A_I), firstname, lastname, phone, email, pass, address_id(link to new_address)
```

**new_address** got:

```
address_id(new), address, city, postalcode, cust_id (link to new_customers)
```

What I already have done:

```
INSERT INTO new_customers firstname, lastname, phone etc etc
SELECT TB_old.firstname TB_old.lastname etc etc from TB_old
```

Where I'm stuck at:

I'm stuck at inserting addresses to the new_address while updating it with the relative cust_id and updating the address_id inside new_customer with the relative address.

EDIT: extra image
to make it clear:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing: Addresses belong to a customer. With that in mind you can do it:

```
INSERT INTO new_customers 
    (cust_id, firstname, lastname, phone, email, password)
SELECT 
    (cust_id, firstname, lastname, phone, email, password)
FROM TB_old;


INSERT INTO new_address
    (address_id, cust_id, address, city, postalcode)
SELECT 
    (null, cust_id, address, city, postalcode)
FROM TB_old;
```

;-)

Answer (score 0):

you are need to link old key and new one. simpliest way: to add field oldKey to the first table, load data to it (storing old keys), and fill second table, using old keys for linking. after all - remove oldKey column.